# android how to find an element defined in view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In android layout xml file a framelayout element is defined like @android:id/tabcontent 
how to refer that element in java code

> = (Framelayout) findViewById(R.id. _ _*_*

so then what is the difference between

> - @android:+id/tabcontent
> - @+id/tabcontent
> - @android:id/tabcontent
> - @id/tabcontent –

Comment: I never used the 1st and 3rd options. I assume that 1st = 2nd and 3rd = 4th but maybe I'm wrong. The difference between the 2nd and the 4th options is that in the 2nd you are declaring the id, as in your case, to reference it later. However, the 4th case is a reference to the id "tabcontent" from the same layout. This can be useful, for example, in RelativeLayouts. An example would be positioning a new view below "tabcontent". You could do this by setting android:layout_below="@id/tabcontent" in the new view.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `android.R.id.tabcontent`

Always remember whenever you use predefined android resources you must use `android.R`

Answer (score 1):

Defining the id as "@+id/tabcontent" you could easily find it as (Framelayout) findViewById(R.id.tabcontent)

Answer (score 1):

if you declared the id of frame layout like @android:id/tab??? so you have to find this framelayout using this.

```
(Framelayout) findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)
```

Answer (score 1):

The + sign adds this `id` to the automatically created `R.java` file (so you can reference the resource using `R.id`) the `android:` means that the resource is inside `android.R.java` file (similar to `R.java`, but refers to android **system** resources). So, as in the other answers `@android:id` refers to `android.R.id`